# Firebase Functions with sub path imports outside of project

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have a firebase functions project with typescript. In this project I use types outside of the project with sub path imports, the result of this is that the build files are skewed.

instead of `main:lib/index.js` I have `main:lib/functions/src/index.js`

`functions/lib`:

```
petertoth@Peters-MBP-2 lib % tree .
.
├── functions
│   └── src
│       ├── index.js
│       ├── index.js.map
│       ├── journalLogs.type.js
│       ├── journalLogs.type.js.map
│       └── util
│           ├── audiFiles.js
│           ├── audiFiles.js.map
│           ├── db.js
│           ├── db.js.map
│           ├── getJournalSettings.js
│           ├── getJournalSettings.js.map
│           ├── prompt.js
│           ├── prompt.js.map
│           ├── storage.js
│           └── storage.js.map
└── types
    ├── firebase
    │   ├── CreateFullRecording.request.js
    │   ├── CreateFullRecording.request.js.map
    │   ├── generateJournal.requests.js
    │   └── generateJournal.requests.js.map
    ├── firestore
    │   ├── JournalSettingsDoc.js
    │   └── JournalSettingsDoc.js.map
    └── openai
        ├── language.js
        └── language.js.map
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
 ...
 "imports": {
    "#types/*": ["../types/*"]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/functions/src/index.js",
  "private": true
  ...
}
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "paths": {
      "#types/*": ["../types/*"]
    }
  },
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

this works well locally, and I can serve it wonderfully. However when I try to deploy:
 `firebase deploy --only functions` I'm getting the following error:

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing ./functions/ directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged XX (98.13 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: ./functions/ folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function generateJournal(europe-west1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function migrageJournal(europe-west1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function getCollectionNames(europe-west1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function createFullRecording(europe-west1)...
Build failed: > build
> tsc

src/index.ts(22,44): error TS2307: Cannot find module '#types/firebase/CreateFullRecording.request' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/index.ts(25,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '#types/firebase/generateJournal.requests' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/util/getJournalSettings.ts(1,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '#types/firestore/JournalSettingsDoc' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/util/prompt.ts(1,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '#types/firestore/JournalSettingsDoc' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/util/prompt.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '#types/openai/language' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/util/prompt.ts(15,31): error TS18046: 'journalBullet' is of type 'unknown'.
src/util/prompt.ts(16,34): error TS18046: 'journalBullet' is of type 'unknown'.
src/util/prompt.ts(48,10): error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'LanguageCode' can't be used to index type '{ en: string; da: string; sv: string; no: string; de: string; }'.; Error ID: 1a2262f3
```

I think there is something wrong with the config of the packaging of files to upload. Just a hunch though and I do not know how to debug this more.

Comment: The Firebase CLI only packages and deploys files within the functions folder.  Everything else is unavailable when Cloud Functions tries to run `npm install` on the project on its own servers, which is why you see those errors.

Comment: I see, however my types are in the lib folder, as such they should also be deployed once the project built. So it should have access to those types but it doesn't...

Comment: No, your "functions" folder is the root of the deployment for Cloud Functions. lib is one folder up, and therefore all the sibling folders to functions are unused. To put it another way "types" is not under "functions", so nothing happens with it at all during deployment.

Comment: Is there a recommended way to do this?

Comment: I think you misunderstand @DougStevenson, the file structure I am showing are the files already built for `functions/lib`.

Comment: It's not real clear because you're not showing one entire tree of files, where package.json exists within that, and the dir where you run the deploy.  It would be more helpful if you construct a minimal repo with unambiguous instructions that anyone could follow to easily reproduce what you observe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update your Firebase CLI:** `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Google Cloud Functions now runs [`npm run build` during deployment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/release-notes#April_11_2023), which seems to cause the issue.

However, as per [this comment by colerogers](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/287#issuecomment-1536373261), the Firebase team patched their CLI to disable this feature in firebase-tools v11.27.0.

> If you upgrade to at least that version, this error should go away without any additional work.

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen the effect where the files move under `lib/functions/src/index.js` with the confusing "src" folder mixed in with the build output. It happens if you reference imports from above the Typscript build folder, without using a "reference" to another TS project. I think this is TSC trying to find the root common path for all imports and shifting the project folder upwards. So then the "src" folder isn't considered special, it's just regarded as some subfolder. It's probably not how you want the build to turn out - even if it *kind of works* locally.

To resolve it you need to add another tsconfig in the "types" folder which makes it its own TS project. Then add a project reference to your main tsconfig:

```
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../types"
    }
  ]
```

and adjust your TS build to use the `--build` flag in `package.json`

```
    "build": "tsc --build ",
```

If you do this, when you rebuild, the main project output will move back up two folders to where it's supposed to be in the `lib` i.e. `lib/index.js` and `lib/util/*` etc. (You will probably need to delete the lib folder first to clean it).

OK this should have fixed the weird build, but when you deploy it still won't upload the lib/types because as Doug explains, they're (now) not in the functions folder, and only referenced locally.

I've solved that before (without requiring a private npm repo or other methods) by using a pre-deploy build script which packages up the lib project into a GZ and adding it as a file dependency to the main project.

In the `package.json` under your "types" library project, you just need the name, version and a build run script:

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm pack"
  },
```

Running `npm run build` will zip up the library like : `my-lib-1.0.0.gz`

You need to copy this file from /lib to /functions/ (or a subfolder).

Then you require the correct version in your main project `package.json` like:

```
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "#types": "file:my-lib-1.0.0.tgz"
  },
```

Then when you deploy the functions, the GZ gets uploaded and resolved during the deployment build from the local file in the container.

I wrote a bash script to do this before deploying which also idiot checks the version like:

```bash
echo Packaging the latest my-lib and import to gcp/functions...
echo Note: the functions package.json must require the new version.
#read -p "Press any key..."

cd libs/my-lib;
# Detect the current version
LIB_VERSION=`node -pe "require('./package.json').version"`

echo Version \($LIB_VERSION\) detected OK?
read -p "Press any key..."

# Package the latest version
LIB_FILENAME=my-lib-${LIB_VERSION}.tgz
npm run build;
# Move it into the Cloud Function folder so the tarfile can be deployed.
mv $LIB_FILENAME ../../gcp/functions;
# Reinstall it locally too
cd ../../gcp/functions;
npm i $LIB_FILENAME
cd ..
```

I'm not sure how the accepted answer could have resolved your question.